# Mapping to React Modal only renders the last item of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-bootstrap

My issue is that when I map the data into the Modal, it is only returning the last item in the array. It looks like it is actually opening a modal for every object in the array and stays open on the last object.

I am also using React-Bootstrap-Table-Next in the same component. The button that I want to trigger the Modal with is currently in a column on the table. I would appreciate some input as I feel like I have hit a wall.

Button being rendered in the table with onClick handler to open the modal:

```
const columns = [
        { dataField: "View", text: "View", 
        formatter: () => {return <Button variant="success" onClick={handleShow}>View</Button>},
        headerStyle: () => {return { width: "5%" };} },
        { dataField: "BusinessName", text: "Business Name", headerStyle: () => {return { width: "27%" };} },
    ];
```

Modal state handling:

```
    const [showModal, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
```

Modal code with map function:

```
<div>
        {submitted.map((submitted) => (
        <Modal 
            show={showModal} 
            onHide={handleClose} 
            size="lg" 
            key={submitted.Id}
            centered
        >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
            
              <Modal.Title>{submitted.BusinessName}</Modal.Title>  
            
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>{submitted.Email}</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Save Changes
            </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
        ))}
        </div>
```

Getting and setting the data:

```
const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState([]);


const getSubmittedData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await Axios.get(url);
            setSubmitted(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
            setLoading(true);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    };
```

Comment: If you inspect the page you see all the modals rendered ? My guess is that the modals are `position:fixed` or `absolute` and they are placed one on top of the other, hence you see only the last one rendered.

Comment: You have your Modal inside the map. This means it will render the modal for each iteration of the `submitted` object. And that's why it seems you only have the last value, because on the last iteration that is the value that you have. You need to move the map inside the modal to 'map' only the values you require. Eg: `{submitted.map(({email}) => email)}`

Comment: @WhiT3Kr0w Thank you for your response, this makes complete sense. I have attempted his however and it seems to map all of the emails in the array instead of the correct one. I feel that this may be to do with the key?

Comment: Added an answer. If you want to show only one record in the modal you wouldn't need a `map` there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do. If you click in a button to show a modal with the information of just one business, you wouldn't need to use `map`. You just pass the object you need into the `Modal` and use that:

```js
        ...
        <Modal.Body>
            <div>Business Name: {business.BusinessName}</div>
            <div>Business Email: {business.Email}</div>
        </Modal.Body>
        ...
```

`business` would be one record filtered from all records (eg: by email), something like:

```js
const business = submitted.find(({email}) => email === 'some.email@example.com')
```

But, if you want to have a list of `submitted` businesses showing in a modal, you need to only include the repeatable elements in the `map`.

In this case we have a modal with its different parts (Header, Footer, Body, etc) which should be an individual object being rendered. You then need to `map` the contents of your `submitted` list and output what you need.

Something like:

```js
    <div>
      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose} size="lg" centered>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Businesses</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          {submitted.map((submitted) => (
            <div key={submitted.Id}>
              <div>Business Name: {submitted.BusinessName}</div>
              <div>Business Email: {submitted.Email}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
```